# How can we do full text search in mysql with special characters like copyright (©), trademark (™), registered ®?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example I have a item_table with description, alias fields, both are indexed like : FULLTEXT KEY `ft_desc_alias_ngram` (`description`,`alias`).

And I have some items like:

```
Test Item 1 ©
Test Item 2 ®
Test Item 3 ™
Test Item 4 © ® ™
```

Now I would like to search for items that have ©, ® or anyone © ® ™. 
To search only © I am using the query:

```
SELECT * FROM item_table WHERE match(description, alias) Against('©' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

but getting no result found.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's built-in fulltext parser is designed for [searching for words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-restrictions.html), not for single characters and comes with default minimum word length setting of 3 ([innodb](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size)) or 4 ([myisam](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len)) These settings mean that no words shorter than 3 or 4 words get indexed and therefore will not be found by a fulltext search. If you change these limits, then the fulltext indexes must be rebuilt - but again, the default fulltext parser was not really meant for searching a single character. Also, you must not forget that natural language mode searches on myisam tables do not return results for words that appear in more than 50% of the records because such words are considered a noise.

If you really would like to search for a single character using fulltext index, then use MySQL's [ngram parser](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search-ngram.html) with token size set to 1 because you are not looking for a word, just for a character.

However, this index would not be useful for searching words within the same fields.

Comment: Thanks @Shadow, got your point but it is not giving result even if with the below syntax: Against('Test ©' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)

Comment: You did not get the point: the default fulltext parser indexes words. Space is obviously considered a word delimiter, so you will never have an entry in the fulltext index that would match `Test @`